# Fix the position of the image bottom-right even after adding list elements using CSS

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

[image]

I want to 'FIX' the image (pencil) bottom-right even after adding elements in list (li). Currently when I adding text in list the image(pencil) moved down which is not what I want. Please suggest.

Html:

```
<div class="notes">
  <h3>Notes</h3>
  <div class="notes-content">
    <div *ngIf="showNotes">
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let note of notesList">
          <span>{{note}}</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="text" name="newNote" placeholder="Type here" [(ngModel)]="newNote" />
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="addNoteBtn">
      <img src="../../common/images/edit-note1.png" alt="Add Note" (click)="addNote()"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.notes {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  h3 {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 17px;
  }
  .notes-content {
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 3px 0 #FFFFFF;
    height: 150px;
    ul {
      padding-top: 10px;
      list-style-type: inherit;
      li input {
        background-color: #171717;
        border: none;
        &:focus {
          outline: none;
        }
      }
    }
    .addNoteBtn {
      float: right;
      margin-top: 15px;
      img {
        cursor: pointer;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Component:

```
  name:string;
  notesList: Array<string> = [];
  newNote: string = '';
  show: boolean = false;
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
    this.notesList = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
    this.show = true;
  }

  addNote(): void {
    this.notesList.push(this.newNote);
  }
```

Sample Plunker:

https://plnkr.co/edit/cFi75ggSA8nESetupOo5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `relative` position on your container `.notes-content`.

And add an `absolute` position on your image.

```
.notes-content {
  position:relative;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 3px 0 #FFFFFF;
}

.addNoteBtn {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:5px;
  right:5px;
}
```

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/O9Ya7hqrrZjZKZ4z0LTy?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks! It works :) Btw. Can you tell me why you use position:relative in .notes-content and position:absolute?

Comment: When you set position `relative` it means that the element will be positioned **relative** to its natural position. So if you don't specify `top`, `bottom`, `left` or `right` - it will not affect it's actual position.  
When you set position `absolute` - the element will be positioned relative to its ancestor (parent container) which has `position` set to anything besides `static`. 
So in order to place `.addNoteBtn` relative to its container `.notes-content` - we have to set container position to `relative`

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work:

CSS

```
.notes-content {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 3px 0 #FFFFFF;
  position:relative;
}

.addNoteBtn img {
  position:absolute;
  right:10px;
  bottom:10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

HTML (I moved `.addNoteBtn` inside the `.notes-content`)

```
     <div class="notes-content">
        <div>
          <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let note of notesList">
              <span>{{note}}</span>
            </li>

          </ul>
          <div class="addNoteBtn">
            <img src="" alt="Add Note" (click)="addNote('gg')"/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/gAOnLpVAHPjeaU6szCH8?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

```
.addNoteBtn{
height:100rem; //adjust as per your need
display:block;
}
.addNoteBtn img{
display:block;
position:relative;
top:50%
transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I am new to Stack overflow. I will fine tune this answer.